# Помогите обдумать логику для RecyclerView adapter

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, recyclerview.adapter

Здравствуйте, у меня имеется `RecyclerView` который выводит списком какое нибудь число и дату, бывают ситуации когда подряд идут несколько строк с одной и той же датой. [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть ли какая то возможность сделать отображение даты только в той строке где дата изменилась? т.е. в первой строке пишем дату, во 2 строке если дата такая же то ее не отображаем, далее если в 3 строке дата изменилась то снова отображаем.

Я так думаю это надо в `CursorAdapter` делать в `getItemViewType`, но никак не могу проработать это.

Answer (score 2):

Сравните дату текущей позиции с предыдущей. Если они совпадают - скрывайте текущую дату.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(AdapterRecycler.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
   if (i>0)
       if (adapterList.get(i-1).getDate==adapterList.get(i).getDate)
           viewHolder.dataText.setVisible(View.INVISIBLE);
       else
            viewHolder.dataText.setVisible(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: я так понимаю в случае с курсором нужно писать  `cursor.moveToPrevious` вместо `i-1` ?

Comment: @Howling, по идее да

Comment: первую позицию (индекс 0) нужно обработать отдельно, чтобы не выйти за границы данных (-1)

Answer (score 2):

Адаптер вашего `RecyclerView` должен только получать массив данных и отображать это.

Так что логику обработки исходных данных нужно выполнять на этапе получения этих данных.

А `getItemViewType` используется в тех случаях, когда в `RecyclerView` требуется отображать элементы, внешний вид которых нужно изменять в зависимости от определённых параметров.

*Как пример, окно диалога (чат), где ваши сообщения отображаются справа, а сообщения собеседника - слева.*

---

Если у вас сложности с проработкой алгоритма, то, на мой взгляд, это будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
// ваш массив с исходным данными
List<Date> dateList = new ArrayList<>();

// массив с отфильтрованными данными для отображения
List<Date> filteredDateList = new ArrayList<>();

// предыдущее значение даты
Date previousDate = null;

for(Date currentDate: dateList) {
   if(previousDate == null || currentDate.compareTo(previousDate) != 0) {
      filteredDateList.add(currentDate);
      previousDate = currentDate;
   }
}
```

**UPD.** Спасибо [@YuraIvanov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6117/yura-ivanov) за замечание. Во время итерации изменять коллекцию нельзя, чтоб не поймать `ConcurrentModificationException`. Переписал с использованием второго массива, который будет отправляться в адаптер

Comment: А вы свой код пробовали запускать? Даже если вы уберете сравнение объектов через ==, у вас будет ConcurrentModificationException. И вопрос почитайте внимательнее, надо не отображать текст если он повторяется, а не весь item убивать. -1

Comment: @YuraIvanov, 1) запускать не пробовал, так как писал с телефона, поэтому прошу прощения, если там оказались эксепшны, я старался передать логику алгоритма 2) вопрос я читал внимательно, а вы почитайте внимательно мой ответ - обрабатывать такую логику во вью холдерах - это неправильно, поэтому можете почитать ещё внимательно строчку комментария в коде, где написал, что можно создавать новый массив с данными, которые требуется отображать

Comment: Нет. В списке должно остаться то же количество элементов, ваш вариант дубли дат просто убирает. Например, если бы это был чат, то задача вывести дату только у первого сообщения дня, а у остальных за день не выводить. Или аватар автора выводить только у первого сообщения от одного и того же автора. Речь не о том где данный алгоритм реализовывать - в холдере, адаптере..., а об алгоритме в принципе.

Comment: @YuraIvanov, согласен, в ваших примерах представлена логика отображения, которая по идее будет лежать на плечах самой View. В случае с задачей из вопроса, на мой взгляд, это можно считать бизнес-логикой, то есть мне в принципе не интересна строка `1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4`. Ведь я в любом случае хочу избавиться от последовательных повторов и получить на выходе `1, 2, 3, 2, 4`. Я к тому, что лишние данные, от которых нужно избавиться, в принципе не должны быть представлены в адаптер